# Ajax POST method

Tags: ajax.net

I am new to Ajax.Net.

I want to know how to access data send from Ajax POST method.
(ie)AjaxObject.send("Some Data")

How to access that "Some Data" in form?

I can access same when i used GET method and passed data in Querystring.
like Request.Querystring("name") in ASP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a Webservice (asmx) on the server. 
You can find good documentation on http://www.asp.net

Specifically around webservices: 
http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/tutorials/ASPNETAJAXWebServicesTutorials.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On the server-side, you access POSTed ajax data the same way you access any POSTed form data:

```
Request.Form("name")
```